# How to use ActionController::TestCase#post to consume a Rest API with http basic auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, testing, rest

How to use ActionController::TestCase#post to consume a Rest API with http basic auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Rails 3, you can set the request env `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` by calling the [encoding_credentials](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html#method-i-encode_credentials) within ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.

```
@request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials("username", "password")
```